# C++. Необходимо открыть тектовый файл и заменить число в нем

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть текстовый файл, в нем массив 4х5 чисел, записанный в строку. Необходимо, чтобы пользователь выбрал один из символов и заменил его на другой. Затем обновленный массив выводится на экран.
Вот, что написала я, все работает, НО! 15 элемент (3 строка, 5 столбец) выводится в обновленном массиве неверно. Например, вместо единички, которая была изначально - 3211265. Кто может объяснить в чем ошибка? :\

```
    void rewrite_matrix (int matrix[4][5])  //программа замены элемента массива
{   int i, j, i0, j0, k;
    cout << "Введите строку: "; cin >> i0;
    cout << "Введите столбец: "; cin >> j0;
    cout << "Введите число, которым хотите заменить элемент массива: "; cin >> k;

    fstream file1;
    file1.open("C:\\SOURCE\\Project_3\\matrix.txt", ios::in);
    fstream file2;
    file2.open("C:\\SOURCE\\Project_3\\matrix.txt", ios::out);

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
       { for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
           { file1 >> matrix[i][j];
             if ((i0==i) and (j0==j))
               { matrix[i][j]=k; }
             file2 << matrix[i][j] << " ";
           }
       }
    file2.close();

        cout << "Массив с измененным элементом:" << endl;
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
       { for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
           { file1 >> matrix[i][j];
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "  "; }
         cout<<endl; }

    file1.close();
}
```

Comment: Увеличьте размер массива до 5 на 6 . Не знаю что делает and но лучше использовать &&

Answer (score 2):

В С++ все индексы нуль-базируемые. Вы обращаетесь за пределы памяти. Сделайте циклы не 1..4 и 1..5, а 0..3 и 0..4 соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо! Не подумала совсем об этом. Теперь все работает точно :)